# Neo4j Configuration with Gephi

Tags: graph, neo4j, gephi

I want to use Neo4j to store a number of graphs I created in python. I was using Gephi for visualization, and I thought the export to Neo4j plugin would be a very simple way to get the data across. The problem is that the server is seemingly not recognizing the neostore...db files that Gephi generated.

I'm guessing I configured things incorrectly, but is there a way to fix that?

Alternatively, I'm also open to importing the files directly. I have two files: one with node titles and attributes and another with an edge list of title to title.

I'm guessing that I would need to convert the titles to ids, right? What would be the fastest way to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the file as tab separated csv files, feel free to import them directly. There are some options, check out this page: http://www.neo4j.org/develop/import

Especially the CSV batch importer can help you: http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/02/28/batch-importer-part-1/

Or if it is just a little bit of data, use the spreadsheet approach: http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/03/importing-data-into-neo4j-spreadsheet.html

Please report back if you were successful.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much. I'll report back in a couple of hours, in case I run into any problems.

Comment: Well, the second batch importer seems by far the most appropriate, but I can't seem to install maven on the Centos. I think I'm going to try some of the other options, or else figure out why the instructions for maven are not working.

Answer (score 0):

I used Gephi to generate a neo4j store file directory in the past - it worked like a charm...
I assume you did delete the default graph.db directory and renamed your gephi-generated directory to graph.db? That worked for me...